# Is $ G(z) = \int_A F(t+z) \, d\mu(t) $ holomorphic provided that $F$ is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, integration

Suppose that $A \subset \mathbb R$ is a compact set. Further, let $\mu$ be a regular complex Borel measure on $A$ and let $F:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be an entire function, i.e. holomorphic over $\mathbb C$. Is it true that
$$
G(z) = \int_A F(t+z) \, d\mu(t)
$$
is a holomorphic function as well? I know that this is true if $d\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Yes, this is true, since differentiation under the integral sign with respect to $z$ is easy to justify.

Comment: Is the same true if I replace $F(t+z)$ be a function $F(t,z)$ where $F(t,z)$ is an entire function of 2 complex variables $t$ and $z$?

Comment: Yes, of course. Since $F$ and $\partial F/\partial z$ are uniformly continuous when $t$ is on $A$ and $z$ on any compact, you can safely differentiate under the integral sign.

Comment: You can as well apply the Morera theorem. In that case change of order of integrals is possible by continuity of  $F(t,z).$

Answer (score 0):

Yes and
$$
G'(z)=\int_AF'(z+t)\,d\mu(t),
$$
since, for any $z,h\in\mathbb C$,
$$
F(z+h)-F(z)=\int_0^h F'(z+w)\,dw
$$
and hence
$$
\frac{1}{h}\big(G(z+h)-G(z)\big)=\frac{1}{h}
\int_A \big(F(z+h+t)-F(z+t)\big)\,d\mu(t)\\ =
\int_A \frac{1}{h}\int_0^h F'(z+t+w)\,dw\,d\mu(t)\to
\int_A F'(z+t)\,d\mu(t)
$$
Above we used Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, since
$$
\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h F'(z+t+w)\,dw\to F'(z+t)
$$
and for any fixed $z\in\mathbb C$, the function
$$
R(h)=\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h F'(z+t+w)\,dw
$$
is bounded for say $|h|\le 1$ since
$$
z+t+h\in z+A+\overline D(0,1)
$$
which is a compact set.